# Fire click event on a highchart column drilldown chart on clicking x axis for drill down reports

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, charts, highcharts

I want to drill down through column chart in highcharts. I have a 3 level drill down with each having at least 20 x-axis labels.Right now drill down is working for column click. I want to do the same thing on x axis click.

Based on my research  i found [this probable solution](http://jsfiddle.net/NULTY/279/). What I want to achieve can be seen here on clicking x-axis labels.

The function i used to achieve this functionality

```
function(chart) {

   //console.log(chart.xAxis[0].ticks[0]);
   $.each(chart.xAxis[0].ticks, function(i, tick) {
       tick.label.on('click', function() {
           var drilldown = chart.series[0].data[i].drilldown;
           if (drilldown) { // drill down
               chart.setTitle({
                   text: drilldown.name
               });
               setChart(drilldown.name, drilldown.categories, drilldown.data, drilldown.color, drilldown.level , drilldown.ytitle);

           } else { // restore
               setChart(name, categories, data, null, level , 'Total Agent score');
               chart.setTitle({text: "Agent Performance Drill Down Report"});

               chart.setTitle(undefined, { text: 'Click the Columns to view Drill Down Reports.' });
           }
       });
   });

}
```

**The problem:** It works with most of the x-labels but not all. This can be seen @ [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NULTY/288/) the label drill down does not work at all 3 levels on all labels.

Also, here is the [post I made on highchart forum](http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=20657) for reference

Comment: i will give a bounty of 100  reputation if correct and optimised answer is found which has no errors as appreciation for your time . since i really need it bad and have lost my way :)

Comment: correct, optimized and error free?! Ain't that just too much to ask for ;)

Comment: ya i understand asking that for a developer is too  great . but who will explain that to the client :D . thanks buddy your solution really made my day . its 99.999 % accurate and optimized .

Comment: @JugalThakkar    but i dont understand when i rotate the lablel to fit more x axis labels . they sometime are garbled  i am using the same code as in the fiddle . i used chrome to form the screenshots .   http://postimage.org/image/hxl012k7z/    and     http://postimage.org/image/mriyd53yf/

Comment: can u share the modified jsFiddle?

Comment: btw sirji question open for bounty :)

Comment: ohh i was out for holiday weekened came back will try to share the fiddle has soon i can get time for it . the fiddle is the same one but just with longer names for me .  i have statretd bounty it will take another 23 hours to award :)

Comment: thanks for the bounty, still awaiting for your jsFiddle on the label issue

Comment: your welcome , i am not getting time in office since i have been given some other work i will update you with fiddle around on this saturday when i get leave . well there was not mucg change in the fiddle just titles are rotated on my side to save space and all x axis labels vary  from min 10 chars to max 50 chars so u can guess .  the fiddle i made was all with short labels so the problem doesnt occur it . i will try if i can update with fiddle any sooner . you might have seen the images i posted that kind of problem i faced .

Comment: this is my updated fiddle 

 http://jsfiddle.net/SBkXL/2/


i havent faced the problem in fidlle yet but it still occurs in chrome and mozilla

Comment: @JugalThakkar did you go through the fiddle i posted . i think you should try that in localhost with the data . i had used 1.7.2 jquery version and latest highharts version from their website .

Comment: Not got the time today, going to be a busy week. I ll look at it at home may be

Comment: ya anytime in week is fine .:)

Comment: All worked well even on localhost. Cross check the highcharts version

Comment: highcharts version and exporting module are latest am using from highhcarts website . and jquery 1.7.2 .  when i close and open again chart then this peoblem occurs . as i say it is random

Comment: it occurs more often for me with this 1.8.2 jquery version this is the script am loading <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

Comment: @JugalThakkar  check this post i have uploaded some screenshots of the problem here http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=20657

Comment: it happens when  i refresh the charts two or three times or when i reopen the closed tab with chart . does work fines sometimes and sometimes comes up with the problem . can it be cause due to some caching

Comment: [jQUery 1.8.2 is not yet fully supported by highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/compatibility). I think this thread is becoming too long now, we should continue the discussion in a chat room/new question/mail.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17228/discussion-between-rinzler-and-jugal-thakkar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the handlers at chart load, some of the axis labels won't be present at that time, hence those labels won't respond to the click event

As a quick (read dirty) fix you can add the same handler that you have for the load to the redraw, so the new labels that are created will bind to it.

You can bind the same function to the redraw (this happens when the x-axis labels are changed too, you can replace with a less frequent event that suits the need too) event, so every time the chart is redrawn you unbind (since I am unsure of the lifetime of the labels in highchart, if an exisiting label is reused for the new drilled down chart, it would be safer to remove) any existing click handler as follows for each tick

```
 $(tick.label.element).unbind('click');
```

and then add the click handler

```
var bindAxisClick = function() {
    $.each(this.xAxis[0].ticks, function(i, tick) {
        $(tick.label.element).unbind('click');
        $(tick.label.element).click(function() {
            var drilldown = chart.series[0].data[i].drilldown;
            if (drilldown) { // drill down
                chart.setTitle({
                    text: drilldown.name
                });
                setChart(drilldown.name, drilldown.categories, drilldown.data, drilldown.color, drilldown.level, drilldown.ytitle);

            } else { // restore
                setChart(name, categories, data, null, level, 'Total score');
                chart.setTitle({
                    text: "Drill Down Report"
                });

                chart.setTitle(undefined, {
                    text: 'Click the Columns to view Drill Down Reports.'
                });
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Modify the chart options to add the redraw and load handlers

```
chart :{
    ...
    events: {
            redraw: bindAxisClick ,
            load:bindAxisClick 
    },
    ...
 }
```

[Dril down from x-axis labels @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/SBkXL/)

Comment: ya i will test it and report to you if it works thank for reply :)

Comment: yes you fiddle really works well thank you again . let me test it my live code :)

Comment: ya when my question becomes available for bounty i will rewrad thank you jugal bhai am from ahmedabad :) it shows will be tommorow .

Comment: this is my updated fiddle jsfiddle.net/SBkXL/2 i havent faced the problem in fidlle yet but it still occurs in chrome and mozilla   . i faced the the problem with rotated problems with fiddle once . but it happens quite often in browser  . sometimes the charts seems to redraw twice too .

Comment: i see the charts now longer work for drill down any problem with latest version 3.0 ??

Comment: @Rinzler unfortunately I haven't worked with Highcharts since some time now, hence haven't tried version 3.0 either

Comment: ven i have not commed to grip with 3.0 . all my export option are failing for 3.0 . so i am side loading 2.3.5 version for now .

Comment: Can any one please update the js files links in the fiddles, because the fiddle are no longer working !:(